# Showing multiple lines for one series in Highcharts

Tags: jquery, json, highcharts

We have 3 parameters like oa,ra,ga and we have multiple channels like ch1,ch2,ch3.
Now the problem is each parameter like (oa,ra,ga) contains all three channels like ch1,ch2,ch3.
And as per the condition i want to show Trend Graph for 3 parameters and each parameter will show 3 lines for each Channels.
How to achieve this.

Kindly help we have invest more that 3 days and finally we are asking in forum.

Regards,
SRD

```
Series:[{
      name:"oa",
      data:[23,12,12,23,23,23,23]//these for ch1
      data:[12,32,23,23,23,23,23]//for ch2
      data:[23,23,23,23,11,11,11]//for ch3
}]
```

now series oa want to show 3 lines ch1 ch2 and ch3 like that i want

Comment: Can you please post some sample data and/or sample post? It's hard to understand your problem.

Comment: please check i have edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I fully understand you, but why don't you just add a new data series for each or the parameters and each of the channels:

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        title: {
            text: 'Sample data',
            x: -20 //center
        },
        xAxis: {

        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'sample data'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: '°C'
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'oa: ch1',
            data: [23,12,12,23,23,23,23]
        }, {
            name: 'oa: ch2',
            data: [12,32,23,23,23,23,23]
        }, {
            name: 'oa: ch3',
            data: [23,23,23,23,11,11,11]
        },{
            name: 'ra: ch1',
            data: [12,23,12,12,23,23,23]
        }, {
            name: 'ra: ch2',
            data: [23,23,23,12,32,23,23]
        }, {
            name: 'ra: ch3',
            data: [11,11,23,23,11,23,23]
        }]
    });
});
```

Demo on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/19pmxa3a/)

Comment: Thanks Reeno, Yes you are right but oa series(ch1,ch2,ch3,etc;) should get reflected in one graph as i select oa. not diffrently for each oa eg: oa ch1,oa ch2,oa ch3 .

Comment: So only oa like in http://jsfiddle.net/19pmxa3a/1/ ? Maybe you can create a simple graph in e.g. Excel to show what you want

Comment: i want to tell u that when i click on oa series it shows all three lines of ch1 ch2 ch3 and when i click on ra it show all related line of ch1 ch2 and ch3

Comment: So there should be something like a link or a dropdown next to the chart to select the series?

Comment: Yes but there should be no need to drop down it shows three lines directly

Comment: I really don't understand you. Please draw something to show what exactly you try to achieve. Or explain it more detailed than just in one sentence.

Comment: ok sir i want a series name oa and when i click on it.. it will be show the three lines on a graph and first line of the graph contains ch1 data and second line contains ch2 data and third line contains ch3 data and same happens with series ra and sa each series will show 3 lines respectively ch1 ch2 ch3 when oa ra and sa enabled it will show me all 9 lines on graph

Comment: Something like drilldown ?

Comment: no sir like One Series having multiple Series Work as Drill Down

Comment: Can you show us a demo/prototype? Did you see such a feature anywhere else so we can look at it?

Comment: actually i have search for it and have not got any result so i approached you and its mandatory to implement

Comment: sir thanks fro your help finally got the solution using linkedTo but there is one problem when i click on the oa or RotorSpeed it doesnt disable the visualization of linked lines